# How make extra div block work as a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have bootstrap 3 page showing only one div for the first time page loads. When I click on the button "Open Next Block" another div shows up, If I click on the 2nd div 3rd div shows up. And in this way I have total 6 divs to show. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq07ysbq/14/)**

Problem is when there are more then 3 divs it goes to the 2nd line which I DON'T want. 
I am trying to make this work as a slider. 
Is this possible to make when there are more then 3 div block the very left div block goes hidden and new div block shows ? like if div 4 shows div 1 goes hidden , if div 5 shows div 2 goes hidden ?

Also when I click the left arrow button, left div blocks will show one by one and right divs hides ?
Mainly it should work as a slider with one by one div movement.

Current jQuery:

```
$("#block-1").click(function() {
    $('#block-2').show();
});
$("#block-2").click(function() {
    $('#block-3').show();
});
$("#block-3").click(function() {
    $('#block-4').show();
});
$("#block-4").click(function() {
    $('#block-5').show();
});
$("#block-5").click(function() {
    $('#block-6').show();
});
```

I am sorry for bad English and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap rows only have twelve columns. If you have each block set to a width of four columns, you can only have three per row. Change their columns to 2 to have six in a row.
This

```
col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4
```

Needs to be

```
col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2
```

As for the slider, there are better ways to do this, but is this what you want? Increment a variable to keep track of what block you are on, then close that with the back button.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lq07ysbq/19/

Comment: But I need them to have like slider :(

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. You want a row of divs that when the last div is clicked increments out, right? Then a single button to increment back?

Comment: Why not just have one button to increment and one to decrement?

Comment: Actually when you clicked on the 3rd Div 1st div goes hidden on the left side and there will be div 2,3 & 4 in one line.

Comment: Oh, so you want to hide the first div on click four, then the second div on click 5? So you only ever have 3 divs at one time?

Comment: You last example is almost what I wanted :) Feeling hopeful. Only thing is when you click the left arrow it show the previous div
LIKE: is the are 4 , 5 and 6 and you click the arrow it will display 3,4,5 and 6 will be again hidden. I can bring 6 back clicking on 5 and it will be 4,5,6 again :) let me know if this make sense. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66148/discussion-between-richard-czechowski-and-raihan).

Comment: This is redundant: col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2, you only need the xs-2, it's the same percentage of the .container or parent